# Windows 10 Pro, WavesNX issue after updating

Tags: windows-10

WavesNX is an audio virtualization software, can be selected the same way as a sound card.
The GUI stopped working after updating from 1909 to 2004. File in question is WavesNxApp.exe.

Waves can still be selected in the os/players and still works. After the update the sound devices were mixed up.

Had a clone of the os on another drive, for testing. There on 1909 Waves works fine.

Tried everything I could think of, updated to the latest os version, whitelisted waves in av/malware, uninstalled av/malware, did a clean boot, reinstalled waves, removed the xonar card and used the onboard sound card, deleted all waves files/registry,

In Resource monitor it shows WavesNX as beeing suspended in 2004, and terminated in the last update. It says access denied when trying to resume or terminate it.

In Event viewer there are some error messages that were not there before, on 2004 and latest version. I will attach some text files with the errors.

Was trying to see if the errors in event viewer were present in before 2004 version, so I installed a new windows installation and starting updating it. It skipped 2004 directly to 20h2. Then updated to the latest.

Waves runs fine.

https://justpaste.it/76byb

So I assume it's something in 2004.

Is there a way to update only to 2004 to test it out?

Comment: 20H2 is 2004 with a few additional features.  You could download a 2004 ISO, choose NOT to install updates, and it would upgrade to 2004.  However, Windows Update will immediately download the enablement package for 20H2 in order to update it.  Actually, since 21H1 is the current version, that’s the enablement package that would be downloaded.  There are no versions between 1909 and 2004 by the way.

Comment: Have you asked Waves' support about it? They're a pretty smart company, well-established in the pro audio world long before they came into the consumer market.

Comment: The process `WavesNxApp.exe` crashes due to an unhandled  exception of Arithmetic Overflow. Only Waves can solve it. Are you using the latest version?

Comment: WavesNX is the latest version. Have been talking with waves support, but it's going slow and I don't know if they can fix the issue. NX hasn't been updated in 3 years.                          don't want to loose the current windows setup even at the cost of not beeing able to use full functionality of waves.



Did two more things, created a new user with admin priv, but waves does not work there either.

Waves also sets itself as primary audio device after each startup, which did not do before.

Comment: New installation with 2004 directly (1904.264), after which installed drivers, audio card drivers, and then waves.
Waves works.
I don't know windows well enough to figure out what's going on.
Maybe when 2004 was updated there was some kind of configuration issue with audio devices, which is why the system is suspending it.

Answer (score 1):

Update, support advised to go to Color Management>Advanced>Device profile to sRGB IEC61966 2.1, and default to the rest as well.
Not sure how, but it fixed the problem.

Comment: Weird! Glad you found it. I used to beta test for Waves, for over a decade, & never saw anything quite as odd;)